# The width of the element's content if it is a child with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a dropdown component (similar to an HTML select). I am working on a content width issue. I need it to behave like an inline-block, but if I set the wrapper class as an inline-block, the width of the content starts to be adjusted according to the width of the button.

How can it be solved so that the width of the content behaves as if the wrapper is set to block even if it is inline-block?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  background: #2c7be5;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #2c7be5;
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button>Toggle box</button>
  <div class="content">
    My box content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue isn't the `inline-block`, but rather the `position: relative` on the `wrapper`. Absolute positioned elements position themselves against the nearest parent element with a position set. You can either add a wrapping element around what you have and leave that as block with `position: relative` OR you can just remove the `position` on the wrapper. But we don't know the rest of your code, so the `content` element may be positioned incorrectly.

Comment: white-space: nowrap to the absolute element?